# Dimensions of Tamron 39FH Hood for SP 300 2.8 LD IF

Tags: lens-hood

I just bought one of these lenses used and it didn't come with a hood and they seem to be few and far between on Ebay.  B&H and Adorama don't have any (or anything that would fit) so I figured I'd try for the next best thing, hardware store DIY.  I did find a guy on youtube that had made his own from a CD tube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvBAYncRl_U
and while I have the tools to do that I'd like to avoid a funky ring hanging on my lens.

So I'm looking for these dimensions of the hood:

- Inside Diameter
- Length
- inset distance of the lock screw
- wall thickness might be nice but I doubt everyone has a set of calipers lying around

OR

any other ideas you might have

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can download a [pattern](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/hoods/Tamron-SP-AF-300mm-f-2.8-LD--IF-.php) to make your own hood from [this site](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/). Please note that the hood will only be the proper size if it is printed without scaling on the designated paper size.

Even if you decide to do something more like what the guy in the DIY video did, the paper/cardboard hood made from printing the above pattern could be measured to help with some of the dimensions you need.

With shorter focal length lenses you can even [create hoods](http://www.lenshoods.net/) that fit the narrower angle of view when using lenses with APS-C cameras. *But with a 300mm lens length is kind of a moot point* since a hood would need to be over a foot long to cause vignetting even with a FF camera when the diagonal angle of view is only about 8º.